# Subset a data frame into 2 data frames based on breaks in the tables

Tags: r, pattern-matching, subset

I have a csv file that I download that contains 3 different tables on the same tab. I only need the top table and the bottom table but depending on when I download the file the number of rows vary. I have attached an image of the file below. [CSV file with the 3 tables separated by blank rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1U8l.png)

What I am hoping to accomplish is reading the 1st table and the 3rd table as two separate dataframes. I was hoping to use grep/grepl to get DF1 up to the 1st break (row 202) and get DF2 starting after the 2nd break (row 212)

I know I can subset the data by going into the file and skipping rows and/or dropping rows. Although I wanted to see if there is a method to automatically identify these tables and subset them.

Answer (score 0):

(The best fix is to correct the origination of this data: don't do this, better to have separate files or some other format. Lacking that ...)

I can only guess from an image, so here's a sample file.

```
a,b,c
1,11,21
2,12,22
,,,,,
aa,bb,cc,dd
31,41,51,61
,,,,,
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
111,222,333,444,555,666
```

Use this function:

```r
##' Read multi-part CSV files.
##'
##' @details
##' A typical CSV file contains rows, unbroken by spaces,
##' with an equal number of columns separated by a fixed character
##' (typically "," or "\\t"). Occasionally, some rows are incomplete
##' (insufficient number of fields); this issue is handled by
##' \code{read.csv} directly with the \code{fill = TRUE} argument.
##'
##' Two other issues can arise in a seemingly compliant CSV file:
##'
##' \itemize{
##'
##'   \item{The header row is repeated multiple times throughout the
##' document. This likely spoils the results from \code{read.csv} by
##' forcing all columns to be factors or characters, instead of the
##' actual data (e.g., numeric, integer).}
##'
##'   \item{There are blank lines separating truly disparate tables.
##' With just \code{read.csv}, the blank lines will typically be
##' \code{fill}ed, all tables will be expanded to the width of the
##' widest table, and all headers will be from the first table.}
##' }
##'
##' This function mitigates both of these issues.
##'
##' NOTE: arguments passed to \code{read.csv} are used with all
##' tables, so if you have blank lines with disparate tables, the
##' presence or absence of headers will not be handled gracefully.
##' @param fname character or vector, the file name(s)
##' @param by.header logical (default TRUE), whether to split by identical header rows
##' @param by.space logical (default TRUE), whether to split by empty lines
##' @param ... arguments passed to \code{readLines} or \code{read.csv}
##' @return list, one named entry per filename, each containing a list
##' containing the recursive tables in the CSV file
##' @export
readMultiCSV <- function(fname, by.header = TRUE, by.space = TRUE, ...) {
    dots <- list(...)

    readlinesopts <- (names(dots) %in% names(formals(readLines)))
    readcsvopts <- (! readlinesopts) & (names(dots) %in% names(formals(read.csv)))

    ret <- lapply(fname, function(fn) {
        txt <- do.call(readLines, c(list(con = fn), dots[readlinesopts]))

        starts <- 1

        if (by.space) {
            starts <- sort(c(starts, 1 + which(txt == ''), 1 + grep("^,*$", txt)))
            stops <- c(starts[-1], length(txt) + 2) - 2
        }

        if (by.header) {
            morestarts <- unlist(mapply(
                function(x,y)
                    if ((x+1) < y)
                        x + which(txt[x] == txt[(x+1):y]),
                starts,
                ## I do "- 2" to remove the empty lines found in the by.space block
                c(starts[-1], length(txt) + 2) - 2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
            starts <- sort(c(starts, morestarts))
            stops <- sort(c(stops, morestarts - 1))
        }

        ## filter out empty ranges
        nonEmpties <- (stops - starts) > 0
        starts <- starts[nonEmpties]
        stops <- stops[nonEmpties]

        mapply(function(x,y) do.call(read.csv, c(list(file = fn, skip = x-1, nrows = y-x), dots[readcsvopts])),
               starts, stops, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    })
    names(ret) <- basename(fname)
    ret
}
```

Demo:

```r
readMultiCSV("~/StackOverflow/11815793/61091149.csv")
# $`61091149.csv`
# $`61091149.csv`[[1]]
#   a  b  c
# 1 1 11 21
# 2 2 12 22
# $`61091149.csv`[[2]]
#   aa bb cc dd
# 1 31 41 51 61
# $`61091149.csv`[[3]]
#   aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
# 1 111 222 333 444 555 666
```

Excel will often out-smart us, and instead have trailing commas in all tables to the right-most edge of the widest. Instead, this will give us a file like:

```
a,b,c,,,
1,11,21,,,
2,12,22,,,
,,,,,
aa,bb,cc,dd,,
31,41,51,61,,
,,,,,
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
111,222,333,444,555,666
```

This doesn't break it, it just gives you more work on the back side:

```r
readMultiCSV("~/StackOverflow/11815793/61091149.csv")
# $`61091149.csv`
# $`61091149.csv`[[1]]
#   a  b  c  X X.1 X.2
# 1 1 11 21 NA  NA  NA
# 2 2 12 22 NA  NA  NA
# $`61091149.csv`[[2]]
#   aa bb cc dd  X X.1
# 1 31 41 51 61 NA  NA
# $`61091149.csv`[[3]]
#   aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
# 1 111 222 333 444 555 666
```

Comment: So I get a very funky output which I belive is what you warned me about. Would it be possible to find the first blank row or let's say the row that contains CxlDate and remove that row along with everything below it? 

Also would it be possible to find the row that contains "MonitoringAccount" and remove all the rows above that but retain the rows below it?

Comment: Those questions seem like questions of *"find a row containing `CxlDate` and remove all below it"* (on a normal `data.frame`), and the reverse with "above". They aren't really about the general sense of reading in multi-table CSV files. I suspect if you think about it, you can find a way to do it post-read instead of turning a function from a general-purpose function to one that will only work in this one situation.